# How to create a unique ID for each record in Structure Streaming

Tags: pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

My structured streaming program is reading data from Kafka.
I have to create Unique ID for each input record. is there any method available for it?

I tried `monotonically_increasing_id()` method, but it is always giving value of 0

```
DF_ID = DF.withColumn("Date",split(col("root"), "\\|").getItem(0)) \
      .withColumn("InventoryAction_SKEY", monotonically_increasing_id())
```

Comment: Why not just randomly generate sufficiently long ID for each record?

Comment: @ranjithreddy If it is being reset to 0, there are can be multiple reasons.The assumption for this method is that the data frame has less than 1 billion partitions and each partition has less than 8 billion records which I hope is not the case. Also, Record ID is transient,  count's value is reset to 0 every time it is  serialized and deserialized and initialize Record ID within each partition